# git flow закрытие локальной фичи

Tags: git, github, git-flow

Есть 2 разработчика. Первый создал feature. Опубликовал ее на удаленном репозитории. Второй выкачал фичу, внес изменения и закрыл фичу, ветка на удаленном репозитории слилась с develop и удалилась. Как теперь первому разрабу закрыть фичу локально? При попытке `git flow feature finish FEATURENAME` пишет:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref feature/FEATURENAME 
Fatal: Could not fetch feature/FEATURENAME from origin.
```

Comment: а просто сделать  `git pull --prune` ?

Comment: Первый разработчик вносил дополнительные изменения? Если не вносил, то ничего делать не нужно, просто забрать код из удалённого репозитория и удалить локальную ветку фичи. Если вносил - то один из вариантов - создать новую фичу на базе ```origin/develop``` и перенести туда новые изменения при помощи cherry-pick.

Comment: А нельзя просто удалить локальную ветку `feature/FEATURENAME`?